# Will g++ optimize this?

Tags: optimization, g++

Will g++ optimize this code by omitting the assignment in "else"?

```
if( a < b ) a = x;
else if( a > b ) a = y;
else a = b;
```

All vars are floats.

Comment: Why not [try it and see](http://godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-O3',source:'int+foo(int+a,+int+b,+int+x,+int+y)%0A%7B%0A++if(+a+%3C+b+)+a+%3D+x%3B%0A++else+if(+a+%3E+b+)+a+%3D+y%3B%0A++else+a+%3D+b%3B%0A++return+a%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3) ?

Comment: you should probably specify what type `a` and `b` are.